# Using variables in a transliteration operator

Tags: regex, perl

This is a stupid question; I need this for something more complicated but let's make it simple:

```
$i = quotemeta 'A';
$line =~ tr/a-z/$i-Z/;
```

This is a silly substitution, this should turn small letters to capital ones, but what ever I tried doesn't work.

Ok so I see this brought lots of confusion, the real code should be:

`$line =~ tr/A-Z/F-ZA-E/;`

It should be a Caesers Chiper algorhytm. This works just fine if you want to change it by a fixed number of letters, but I need a variable so I could change it as many number of letters as I want to. But I want to ship eval
Thnx

P.S. Also, why doesn't s/// work with ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need tr, you could use eval:

```
$i = quotemeta 'A'
eval("\$line =~ tr/a-z/$i-Z/;");
```

Comment: Best test `$@` after every `eval`, no?

Answer (score 4):

Note that with `tr///`, you can only use literal characters, not variables. So, `tr/a-z/$i-Z/` does not work, you'd have to use `tr/a-z/A-Z/`. In [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) you can read more about `tr///` and also find the explanation on interpolation or lack thereof.

To turn a string into upper case, though there are other ways. You can use the [`uc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/uc.html) function, or the regex escape sequences [`\U`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers) (upper case) and [`\L`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers) (lower case). E.g.:

```
my $str = 'a';
my $uppercase = uc $str;
```

Regex:

```
my $str = 'abcdef';
$str =~ s/([a-z]+)/\U$1/;  # $str is now 'ABCDEF'
```

tchrist points out that `[a-z]` should be written `\p{CWU}`, which will include all characters which are affected by case.

**Update:**

If you're trying to create some kind of dynamic encoding feature, I would suggest a subroutine that takes the arguments, and moves the characters around manually.

```
sub foo {
    my ($str, $num) = @_;  # num is how many characters to shift the alphabet
    my @in  = 'A' .. 'Z';
    my @out = @in[$num .. $#in, 0 .. $num-1];
    my %out = map { $in[$_] => $out[$_] } 0 .. $#in;
    $str =~ s#(.)# $out{$1} // $1 #eg;  # if key does not exist, use org
    return $str;
}
```

Note that it is case sensitive, but you can add keys for lower case to solve that.

Comment: Moreover, you very much *should* use `uc` for uppercase, `ucfirst` for titlecase, `lc` for lowercase, or v5.16’s `fc` for foldcase. Never do it the nasty broken ASCII way.

Comment: @tchrist And which way is that? Escape sequences? Why is that broken?

Comment: You’ll hate me, but you really mean `$str =~ s/(\p{CWU}+)/\U$1/g` you know. Seeing `[a-z]` is really an anti-pattern in the post-ASCII age.

Comment: I meant that you don’t want `tr/a-z/A-Z/` or even `s/([a-z]+)/\U$1/g` for the reasons I just mentioned. You should train yourself to use `\p{lower}` if you mean lowercase, and to use `\p{CWU}` if you mean things that change when uppercased. Also, note that there are `\p{lower}` that are not `\p{CWU}`, and there are `\p{CWU}` that are not `\p{lower}`.

Comment: You may of course use the five case-related escape sequences (`\L`, `\l`, `\U`, `\u`, and v5.16’s `\F`) in the replacement string portion of a `s///`, since they compile into the function calls anyway.

Comment: @tchrist That is interesting. I'll try to remember that.

Comment: `\p{CWU}` is actually the shorthand for `\p{Changed_When_Uppercased}`. There’s also `Changes_When_Titlecased` (CWT), `Changes_When_Lowercased` (CWL), `Changes_When_Casefolded` (CWCF), `Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded` (CWKCF), and `Changes_When_Casemapped` (CWCM).

Comment: @tchrist Ok, that's too much information. =P Plus, I had already googled the meaning of CWU.

Comment: @tchrist Btw, I see that `\p{CWU}` does not include the swedish `åäö`. I thought this was a complete collection of capitalizable characters.

Comment: @TLP Sure it does. `perl -Mutf8 -Mv5.14 -E 'say for "åäö" =~ /\p{CWU}/g'` correctly produces three lines of output, one per letter.

Comment: @tchrist If I try `perl -Mutf8 -Mv5.14 -plwE "s/\p{CWU}/X/g"` and enter `fooåäö` I get `XXXåäö`, and with your example I get `Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at -e line 1.` I suppose it might be a Windows cmd shell thing.

Comment: If you’re reading from UTF-8, add `-CSD`. I have `PERL_UNICODE` set to `SA` in my environment. I always forget other people do not.

Comment: Yes, it works when used in a source file, however, I have to remove the `use utf8` statement, or I get `Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0xe4, immediately af
ter start byte 0xe5) at ...`

Comment: `utf8 "\x86" does not map to Unicode // Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at..` This stuff isn't meant to be easy, is it? =)

Answer (score 2):

Your example is unfortunately not a good one; the `tr` operator doesn't accept any variable interpolation (in either half).  If you are actually using `tr`, you are out of luck unless you resort to `eval`, which is not recommended.  If you're not using `tr`, then please show us the actual code so we can see what's going on and offer more suggestions.

**UPDATE**

How about this?

```
my %map;
@map{'A'..'Z'} = ('F'..'Z','A'..'E');
s/[A-Z]/$map{$&}/g;
```

Not sure if it's still true, but once upon a time `$&` was to be avoided at all costs due to a terrible performance penalty.  You can do so easily enough:

```
s/([A-Z])/$map{$1}/g;
```

Comment: Stop.  There is nothing unrecommended about using `eval` for this purpose. Sheesh.

Comment: @tchrist Except that it's overkill, perhaps. I would argue that its better to learn the proper techniques than relying on eval to hack things up.

Comment: @tchrist - well, ok, it's unrecommended by me.  IMO, `eval` *string* is almost never the right answer. Too often it seems to be a lazy (in the lowercase, non-virtuous sense) shortcut, which opens up a whole new can of worms as far as the sort of exceptional conditions you have to watch out for.  It also tends to perform poorly, though performance doesn't always matter.

Answer (score 0):

tr doesn't work with variables; use s/// (substitution) instead.

Comment: How would you suggest such a substitution looks like for the range `a-z`? This is not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I can't get a range with s///
Are there any other functions that have ranges and that are not tr and s

Comment: You *can* use a range. Like I showed in my answer. My point was that Kenosis did not specify how its done, with `\U`.

Comment: Your substitution only changes the first letter in the line

Comment: @TLP Agreed.  My response was not helpful.